# What is the second (blue) Pokémon movement option?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When using Organize Boxes, there are three buttons at the top that determine how to move Pokémon, the red (o), blue (o)<->(o) and green [88]-> buttons.

Obviously, the red button is for normal movement and the green one allows you to select multiple Pokémon at the same time. However, I can't for the life of me figure out what the blue button is supposed to do. It seems to do the exact same thing as the red button.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have wondered the same thing many a times!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more experimenting, I managed to stumble over the answer. For future reference, I'll just post it here.

The regular red mode allows you to tap a Pokémon to bring up the menu (Move, Summary, Item etc.) while blue does not; it's used exclusively for moving. More significantly, when using button controls, selecting a Pokémon in blue mode skips the menu and immediately prepares the Pokémon for moving.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to move pokemon around, especially when sorting them into different boxes!

Comment: Yea it is probably for those people that don't want to use the stylus.

Comment: @Reafexus: Ah, I never thought about that as I always use the stylus. Yeah, I suppose that makes sense then. :)

Comment: It also happens frequently (even with the stylus) that you accidentally open the menu. That wastes a little time and is kind of tiring after a while. I've come to really appreciate the "no-menu" advantage of the blue marker and use it most of the time when I'm not using the green one. The touchscreen just doesn't always track the stylus movement perfectly, sometimes due to dust or dirt on the screen, and if you use the red marker, this often opens the menu without you wanting to actually open it.